# Timestamp when value of cell changes

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm creating a google sheet app script that will log the timestamp to another row (Column 40) upon editing of other cell value (column 3). This is what I have so far

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVIoB.png)

It works, however, whenever I paste values to column 3 with a range of more than 1 cell, the script is just updating the 1st row. Result is something like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08qxu.png)

Appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please replace the image of code with a text-based [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the alert dialog?

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('row = ' + row + '\ncol = '+ col)

You can use it to debug your code. As you posted an image, I used it show where to insert this line and see what exactly are the values of your variables 'row' and 'col'.

[image: same image of the question with red mark where to insert code]

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, pop-up window just showed 
row = 943
col = 2
Is it because the "getRange and Offset" are capturing just the active cell, not the active selection?

Answer (score 0):

use offset instead of getRange

e.range.offset(0,38-col).setValue(currentDate)

Comment: hello, I tried using offset, but getting the same result. I'm thinking that this is because "Offset and getRange" are just capturing data from the active cell/row? I tried using this code   var currentDate = new Date ();
  e.source.getActiveSheet().offset(row,38).setValue(currentDate);
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().offset(row,37).getValue() == ""){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().offset(row,37).setValue(currentDate);

Comment: use e.range.offset NOT e.source.getActiveSheet().offset